# YAF 1.9.5.5: Integrate MVC 3 with YAF (login and register)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forum, yetanotherforum, yaf

i have a MVC 3 project and want to integrate YAF forum inside of my project, but i dont know how to make a register page and login page (in MVC 3 project) that when i register an account, YAF create an user too, the same with login page, i just want user can register and login in my MVC project and then go to the YAF forum

Thanks and sry 4 my E :)

Comment: YAF forum is a great project, but it should be easier to integrate your MVC site with a MVC forums, like Nearforums. Disclaimer: I'm a developer for the Nearforums project team.

Comment: Nice, just have a watch to Nearforums :), it's cool, keeps it up

Answer (score 0):

The **YAF.Providers.YafMembershipProvider** module makes a call to **dbo.yaf_prov_createuser** stored procedure in the DB when creating users.

You can call that yourself to create a user. You'll be bypassing a few validation routines so you need to make sure the user info you pass in is unique (i.e. email and username).

Then all you're missing is to set **yaf_prov_Membership.IsApproved = True** once you've validated the email.